# Help me understand/translate "不留到晚自习就写完多好" (context supplied)

Tags: translation

I'm struggling to understand this sentence. It's in an answere [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/48971187), about halfway down the page. I've copied the context below:

> 一部分是课代表。我是语文课代表 也很喜欢语文老师 他忘了留作业的话 我就在座位用口型告诉他 作业。然后他就
>   噢今天的作业啊，巴拉巴拉。这样可以避免我去办公室问作业 作业总是要有的啊。 一部分单纯热心。**而且想提前写作业 不留到晚自习就写完多好**。
>   最少的一部分是自己从来不写作业 但不能让别人没有作业。这种可能很小。

Anyone able to help me out with this? I'm HSK5 so I know the general meaning of the characters in the sentence but I can't figure out the overall meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain which bits, in particular, you’re struggling with? I’m guessing it’s probably just that you don’t know what **晚自习** is. 晚自习 = (mandatory) evening study hall. Maybe you can piece it together knowing what it is.

Comment: So the 留 in 不留到晚自习 is not from 留作业, but rather refers to the student "leaving" the homework until later, right? Similar to 拖到. In that case, why is it 就写完 in the latter part of the sentence? Shouldn't it be 才写完? Like this 不 留到晚自习才写完 多好 "not leaving it until 晚自习 to finish it is so great".

Comment: 就 has many meanings, the following may apply (s. 汉语虚词学习手册）[Adverb] Used in a main clause,to show a conditional, causal, consequential, selective relationship, e.g. 下班以后，他就回家了。

Answer (score 2):

Because there is some uncommon term that OP don't understand.

`课代表` so call "class/course representative", is in fact, a helper/assistant roles appointed by the tutor/teacher.  So the author is a "helper" .

这样可以避免我去办公室问作业  : So as a helper, he/she may need to go to the teahcer office to ask about home work for the student if the teacher forget about it.

而且想提前写作业 不留到晚自习就写完多好. What the author mean the he/she are able to do the home work immediately during those spare time between the class, rather than leaving it overnight.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, it took me 3-5 seconds to understand this sentence, given that I'm quite familiar with this context about being a student. Perhaps the answerer wrote quickly on social media and didn't read the sentence again. I think it can be better reworded as

> 不留到晚自习,在晚自习之前就写完(作业)多好
>
> It will be good if I can finish the homework before the evening class. I don't have to leave it until the evening class.

You can see there are some duplication here and the order is different from that in English, but it's quite common in Chinese to emphasize or provide more context so it's more fluent to read.

Answer (score 1):

The 不留到晚自习 elaborates on the point the speaker made about 想提前写作业. As you can see in the beginning of the passage, the speaker reminds the teacher about the homework (他忘了留作业的话 我就在座位用口型告诉他 作业). They want to complete the homework early (提前写作业) instead of procrastinating it to when they would have to write it all on their own instead of getting help from the teaching assistant or any tutors (留到晚自习). The sentence in question is comparing the two possible situations: completing the homework early with resources to help them if they get stuck, or writing it last minute without any help.

Answer (score 1):

The translation to the **bold** part would probably be:

> It is also because I wanted to start working on my homework earlier;
>   wouldn't it be nice if I could finish it early so that I don't have to stay late to work on it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Translation below:
...
Part (of them) are assistants of the course. I'm the assistant for Chinese, and I like the Chinese teacher. If he forgets about leaving homework, I will say with mouth at my seat but without voice: "Homework, Homework..."Then, he'll say: "Oh, today's homework is blablabla..." This can save my time going to his office and ask for homework. After all, homework is necessary.
Part (of them) are simply enthusiastic. They even want to do homework in advance. It's better not to leave it until the evening self-learning time.
The least part (of them) never do their own homework, but also never let others be without homework. This is quite rare.

It's good to...=...(该)多好.